# SOAP Request return a null response

Tags: php, soap

I am not familiar with SOAP webservices but, i need consume one for a project.
Acording the [specification](http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx), the webservice has 3 (three) methods:

- Enviar
- Consultar
- Validar

So, i use an instance of SoapClient:

```
# http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx?WSDL
$this->client = new SoapClient(static::SERVICE_WSDL, [
     'exceptions' => 1,
     'trace' => 1
]);
```

I think that, i can't use the "auto mapped" methods because i need sign the XML data.

So, i use the `SoapClient::__doRequest` method:

```
# Enviar
$this->operation = $operation;
# http://tempuri.org/Enviar
$action = 'http://tempuri.org/' . $operation;
# http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx
$location = static::SERVICE_URL;
$v = SOAP_1_1;
$data = $this->xml->saveXML();
try {
   $this->client->__doRequest($data, $location, $action, $v);
   var_dump($this->client->__getLastResponse());
} catch(SoapFault $e) {
   var_dump($e);
}
```

My problem is that, the SoapClient::__getLastResponse() always return null. Any ideas ?